# JPanel not refreshing upon selection with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

I am attempting to write a pretty short class that "ties" a JPanel to a JComboBox.  I think I have the logic down, but nothing happens when I select something new using the JComboBox...  Here is (more or less) my code:

```
private DisplayPanel currentDisplay; //a displaypanel is simply an extended JPanel with an id field, and an overriden .equals() method
private JComboBox selector;
private List<DisplayPanel> displays;

public SelectionPanel(DisplayPanel panel){
    displays = new ArrayList<DisplayPanel>();
    selector = new JComboBox(new String[]{panel.id});
    currentDisplay = panel;
    selector.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(selector);
    this.add(currentDisplay);
    this.displays.add(panel);
}

public void addNewSelection(DisplayPanel panel){
    displays.add(panel);
    selector.addItem(panel.id);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox source = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
    String id = (String) source.getSelectedItem();
    for(DisplayPanel display: displays)
        if(id.equals(display.id))
                currentDisplay = display;
    this.validate();        
}
```

I am assuming I need to override the repaint() function somehow, but I am really not sure the best way to do that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think you should be completely replacing that panel every time.  (I'm not 100% sure though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is (more or less) my code:

Which doesn't help us because we don't know the context of how the code is used. For better help post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) when asking a question.

> currentDisplay = display;

That line of code doesn't seem correct. All it does is change the value of a variable. It does not add the panel to the GUI. You basic code would be:

```
panel.remove( theOldPanel );
panel.add( theNewPanel );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

However, this is exactly what a CardLayout does for you, so the proper solution is to follow aardvarkk's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

When you add currentDisplay to the GUI, you're not adding the currentDisplay *variable* to the GUI, but rather the *object* that the currentDisplay variable refers to. So later when you change what component the currentDisplay variable refers to, it should make sense that this will have absolutely *no effect* on the component displayed by the GUI since it still holds the original object.

I second the excellent recommendation by aardvarkk that you use a CardLayout (1+ to aardvarkk). If you do this, you will find that it will work smoothly (and then you should accept Aardvarkk's answer as *the* answer).